# UILabel add exclusion path

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

How to add exclusion path for `UILabel` in iOS?

From iOS 9, `UILabel` has been implemented on top of TextKit, that means you can set an exclusion bezier path.

Suppose we have an multi-line (3 in my case) `UILabel` with a image on the right and the image height is less than the height of the `UILabel`. Using a `UITextView` I can do the following:

```
UIBezierPath * imgRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imgRect];
```

and the text would nicely flow around the image. This is done by setting the exclusion path of the UITextView to the image Frame. How to do the same this with `UILabel` since there is no TextContainer property.

I added below an example of how it is done using `UITextView`.

https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/280-flowing-text-around-images-with-exclusion-paths

[The text without setting the excluison path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN3x1.png)

[This is the text with the exlusion path set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv27A.png)

Comment: Can you please be a bit clear on your question. I am not able to understand your issue is . Adding some code snippet will be helpful

Comment: Suppose we have an multi-line (3 in my case) UILabel with a image on the right and the image height is less than the height of the UILabel. 

Using a UITextView I can do thew following 

UIBezierPath * imgRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imgRect];

and the text would nicely flow around the image. This is done by setting the exclusion path of the UITextView to the image Frame.
How to do the same this with UILabel since there is no TextContainer proprety.

Comment: You don't seem to have access to the `NSTextStorage` property of a `UILabel` but you have it in `UITextView`. I'd tend to suggest using a `UITextView`, modify a little its properties to make it more `UILabel` look alike and then use its `exclusionPath`.